# Convert the postgres select query into a function that accepts date range and dynamically add them in the select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
  job_description,
  SUM(CASE WHEN end_date::date = '2023-06-05' THEN time_rendered ELSE 0 END) AS "2023-06-05",
  SUM(CASE WHEN end_date::date = '2023-06-06' THEN time_rendered ELSE 0 END) AS "2023-06-06",
  SUM(CASE WHEN end_date::date = '2023-06-07' THEN time_rendered ELSE 0 END) AS "2023-06-07",
  SUM(CASE WHEN end_date::date = '2023-06-08' THEN time_rendered ELSE 0 END) AS "2023-06-08",
  SUM(CASE WHEN end_date::date = '2023-06-09' THEN time_rendered ELSE 0 END) AS "2023-06-09",
  SUM(CASE WHEN end_date::date = '2023-06-10' THEN time_rendered ELSE 0 END) AS "2023-06-10"
FROM (
  SELECT
    a.job_description,
    b.end_date::date,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(SUM(to_seconds(AGE(b.end_date, b.start_date)::text)), NULL), 0) AS time_rendered
  FROM profile a
  LEFT JOIN manhour b ON a.account_id = b.account_id
  GROUP BY a.job_description, b.end_date
) subquery
GROUP BY job_description
ORDER BY job_description;
```

The result of the code is the following(sort of like a onehot encoding):

result of the select query

[image]

When I converted it to a function, i find it hard to specify the return columns(which are the dates in the SUM aggregation)

Comment: is the number of returning columns variable?